# Finding Synonyms for Compound words like Call-Taxi , Artificial Intelligence using NLTK or Spacy?

Tags: python, nltk, spacy

Synonyms in Python can be easily found using NLTK or Spacy for a single word like Cat, Dog, Happy, or sad But when it comes to compound words like Artificial- Intelligence or Call-Taxi the language processor always gives output for each and every token instead of giving synonyms for the entire word .i.e Artificial-synoyms-unnatural, feigned, false & Intelligence- intellect, brain, mind. But I need to find synonyms for Artificial Intelligence as a single compound word which should yield a result like robots, system intelligence &, etc. I would be happy if someone provides me a small snippet.

```
> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn print
> wn.synset("eat.v.01").lemma_names # prints synonyms of eat print
> wn.synset("Artificial Intelligence").lemma_names # throws WordNetError
```

Using Artifical_Intelligence with an underscore also does not work.

Comment: What are the synonyms for `Call-Taxi` or `whole foods`?  `Call-taxi` is an action, so it's doubtful there are any synonyms.  `Whole foods` will also have no synonyms.  Can you share more of the list that you are trying to query for?

Answer (score 0):

As a start point,

```
print(wn.synset("artificial_intelligence.n.01").lemma_names())
```

prints 'AI'.

It doesn't work for "call_taxi" but it can still be interesting for basic usage.

Comment: bro I want to know the synonyms for artificial intelligence as a whole I want it for other words too like whole foods, mid-day & etc

Answer (score 0):

Try using [sense2vec](https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec), either with one of the pretrained models or training it yourself on a large corpus like Wikipedia. You can check out a demo of it [here](https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec).

This won't work for "call taxi" though, for multi word expressions it only works for noun phrases.

If you want similar phrases to "call taxi" those wouldn't be called synonyms, it's more like a semantic similarity problem, or maybe a paraphrasing problem. Without more context I'm not even sure what you'd want for "call taxi" - "order taxi", "call cab", something like that? That's a more difficult problem.